# Deserialization of JSON containing "Unique Values" - RestSharp

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, restsharp

I have seen examples of deserializing a JSON, but my JSON has unique values

```
{
  "-JxsJFiGBqQz1KQmmR0i" : {
    "bizcardData" : {
      "company" : "Tesla",
      "designation" : "Developer",
      "email" : "phani@tesla.com",
      "name" : "Phani",
      "phone" : "5135921241"
    },
    "transData" : {
      "date" : "15-08-29",
      "location" : "39.1395996,-84.5295417",
      "tag" : "sender",
      "time" : "03:17:00"
    }
  },
  "-JxsJKnJIVTFQWE1aSOr" : {
    "bizcardData" : {
      "company" : "Spotify",
      "designation" : "Designer",
      "email" : "komarapa@spotify.com",
      "name" : "Phani Komaravolu",
      "phone" : "5135921241"
    },
    "transData" : {
      "date" : "15-08-29",
      "location" : "39.1395996,-84.5295417",
      "tag" : "sender",
      "time" : "03:17:21"
    }
  }
}
```

I am using a called Transactions which contains List> for the **bizCardData** and **transData**. I don't need to store the Unique values. Just the two lists of values.

Please share the code of how to Deserialize the JSON with unique values using JSON and if possible, please shed some light on how to construct the class best, to store the values.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RestSharp](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Deserialization) supports deserializing JSON objects with arbitrary names to .Net dictionaries.  Given the classes:

```
public class BizcardData
{
    public string company { get; set; }
    public string designation { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
}

public class TransData
{
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public string tag { get; set; }
    public string time { get; set; }
}

public class Transactions
{
    public BizcardData bizcardData { get; set; }
    public TransData transData { get; set; }
}
```

You can deserialize and serialize your JSON like this:

```
        var resultList = SimpleJson.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Transactions>>(json);
```

Or, alternatively,

```
        RestSharp.RestResponse response = new RestSharp.RestResponse();
        response.Content = json;

        JsonDeserializer serializer = new JsonDeserializer();

        var resultList = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Transactions>>(response);
```